# Why is React Native's Text.onTextLayout not being called?

Tags: react-native, text, layout

I have a custom component which contains a `<Text>` component, and there is a handler on the `onTextLayout` callback of the `<Text>`:

```
  <Text style={style}
    onTextLayout={(e) => {
      ...
    }}
  >...</Text>
```

This component is used at several locations in the app. At some of them, the `onTextLayout` callback is called correctly. At other locations, it is not called at all. No matter what I put in the callback (`console.warn`s, `throw`s, etc.), the component renders but my `onTextLayout` callback is not called.

What could be the reason for this? Is there a (documented) scenario in which a `Text` is rendered on the screen without `onTextLayout` being called?

Comment: Can you paste the code from a component where it's working and a component where it's not?

Comment: I can, but it would involve a lot of explaining, because there are many custom made components involved. I think it would be nearly the same as isolating the problem. I can do that, but before doing it I wanted to know whether this was by design - is the Text component designed in a way that it does not always call onTextLayout?

Comment: No, it should be called whenever the text layout changes. However if the screen is never unmounted and you navigate back to it, it won't be laid out again.

Comment: I'm talking about the first time the screen is shown, the first time the Text component is rendered. So you're saying it is called whenever the layout changes - I was expecting it to be called also the first time it gets its layout. On the one screen we have, this works as expected, but not on the second one. Seems to be a React Native bug.